# Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++, dll

I am encountering a weird error when attempting to run an application (which I haven't changed the code for for a while as it works okay) linking to my DLL.  This DLL used to work, but I've been making changes to the DLL's code and got it to compile okay.  Unfortunately, when trying to run the application...

```
---------------------------
GameTest001.exe - Entry Point Not Found
---------------------------
The procedure entry point ??0Music@@QAE@ABV0@@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library Renderer02.dll. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have no idea how to interpret this error.  I know what changes I have made, and my code looks fine to me.  I've tried Googling this and had no luck at all.

Can anyone shed any insight to this?  What does this error mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are linking to a function that has been exported with a mangled name, and that name is `??0Music@@QAE@ABV0@@Z`. The DLL that is being loaded does not export a function of that name and hence the error.

The name mangling encodes the function's name, parameters and return value. So the most likely cause for the mismatch is that you have changed the name, parameters or return value of the function in one place but not the other.

If you have changed the DLL you'll need to re-compile it to produce new .lib and .dll files. You will also have modified the .h file. Make sure that the modified versions of all three of those files are used by the program that links to the DLL.

This error message is actually helpful to you because it will make sure that both sides of the interface match before you can proceed to execute the code.

**Update**

I didn't make it clear enough in the text above. Whenever you change the interface of the DLL you must do the following:

1. Update any .h files that are used by the application.
2. Re-compile the DLL to produce new .lib and .dll files.
3. Re-compile the application using the updated .lib and .h files.
4. Distribute the new .dll file so that the updated application loads the updated DLL.

Comment: I'd rebuilt the DLL and its lib files many times to no avail.  However it seems I actually needed to rebuild the application I've not needed to rebuild for weeks that has been using each new version of the DLL.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. You've changed the DLL and so in order to use the new .dll file you need to compile the application with new versions of the .h and .lib files.

Comment: You didn't mention that I needed to recompile the application as well (previous changes to the DLL didn't necessitate a need to recompile the application).

Comment: Sure I did: "Make sure that the modified versions of all three of those files are used by the program that links to the DLL." You have to realise that you need to make both sides of the interface match. If you change one, you must change the other to match. Your previous changes to the DLL did not change the interface, only the implementation.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what may have happened then.  Although I have created new header files in the past for this DLL, none of the new header files etc were ever called (or used originally) by the application.  However, I DID rename a .h file in another part of the DLL recently, and then made a new one with the same name (but with different functionality).  These two files did not declare or define the `Music` class, but one of them did use it.  The changing of the use of this .h file, I'm guessing that could be what caused this?

Comment: It's hard for me to follow without knowing all the details. But clearly there's a mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications.  So basically it was just luck that it carried on working when I was making changes previously? :P  And that general good practice would be that if I make changes to the DLL (and then build/rebuild it), rebuild the application that uses it?

Comment: The nice thing about using mangled names is that you will learn at runtime if you have made a change that affects the interface. If you are changing the DLL but leave the interface un-modified, then you don't need to re-build the app. It's only if you change function names, parameter types, return types or calling convention that you are changing interface and so require app re-build.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the function `Music::Music(class Music const &)` is missing from your dll. `??0Music@@QAE@ABV0@@Z` is the mangled name for this function. You can demangle function names using [this site](http://demangler.com/).

Comment: Demangling won't solve the problem. The solution is to make sure both DLL and app match.

Comment: Yes, but knowing what the demangled stuff actually is is still useful, surely?

Comment: There are times when demangling is useful but if you actually want to solve your problem you need to understand which files are input to the DLL, and which are produced as output to the DLL compilation. And likewise for the application. You need to understand that you have two sides of an interface that need to match. And you need to understand that when you change one side of an interface you must change the other to match. Demangling is not part of any of that.

Answer (score 2):

Give a second look in the compiler flags to check whether *-static-libstdc++* is included.In such case you d have to rebuild the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your c++ code

```
extern "C"
{
   inline  __declspec(dllexport)  int MyFunction()
  {
     return  63;
  }
}
```